# Git - Programatically determine if local commits have not been pushed

Tags: bash, git, push

I've seen lots of posts/answers on how to display all of the local commits for all local branches that have not been commited.

I have a narrow use case, and have not found an answer.

I need to determine from within a bash script, if my CURRENT branch has commits that have not been pushed upstream to the same branch. A count would be fine, but I really just need to know if a push has not yet been done. I don't care about any branches except the current branch, and in this case I've already checked to see if the branch is local (i.e. has not yet set upstream origin).

Mainly, I don't want the commits printed out. I just want to know that the number of unpushed commits is > 0.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The upstream of the current branch is `@{u}`. `@` is a synonym for `HEAD`.

`@..@{u}` selects the commits which are upstream, but not local. If there are any you are behind. We can count them with `git rev-list`.

```
# Move 4 commits behind upstream.
$ git reset --hard @{u}^^^

$ git rev-list @..@{u} --count
4
```

`@{u}..@` does the opposite. It selects commits which are local but not upstream.

```
# Move to upstream
$ git reset --hard @{u}

# Add a commit
$ git commit --allow-empty -m 'test'
[main 6dcf66bda1] test

$ git rev-list @{u}..@ --count
1
```

And if both are 0 you are up to date.

Note: this will only be "up to date" as of your last fetch. Whether you want to combine this with a fetch is up to you, but one should get used to the fact that Git does not regularly talk to the network.

(I've borrowed from [ElpieKay's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66540136/14660)).

See [gitrevisions](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions) for more about `@`, `..` and many ways to select revisions.

Comment: From the [git book §3.5](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches) _"Git moves [remote-tracking branches] for you whenever you do any network communication"_. So make sure you made a recent network-based command like `fetch`.

Comment: I can see how this gives me a commit tag for local and remote, but if they don't match, it doesn't tell me if I am ahead or behind.

Comment: @svenyonson If they're different, if `git branch --contains <current>@{upstream}` has <current> you're behind. Otherwise ahead. (On a phone)

Comment: (sorry I accepted the wrong answer above by mistake, fixed now)

Comment: Yes, exactly. I might also want to know if local needs to do a pull. So I can do both tests.

Comment: @svenyonson I borrowed from ElpieKay's answer and streamliined it.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the branch is `foo`.

```
git fetch origin foo
git rev-list FETCH_HEAD..foo --count
```

The 1st command gets the latest head of the `foo` in the remote repository and stores its commit sha1 in `FETCH_HEAD`.

`git rev-list` returns a number. If it's 0, all commits of the `foo` in the local repository have been included in the `foo` branch in the remote repository. If it's larger than 0, there are this number of commits not included in the remote `foo` yet.

Being included is different from being pushed if the procedure involves a pending change like a pull request or a merge request. The commands can determine if the local branch's commits have been merged to(included in) its remote counterpart.

Comment: I think this is what I am looking for. Question: Can the returned count be negative, and if so, does this mean that the local repo is behind (n commits) from the remote?

Comment: Or perhaps I do the same command reversing the arguments to foo..FETCH_HEAD to determine if the local repo is behind?

Comment: @svenyonson It can't be negative. `foo..FETCH_HEAD` refers to the commits  reachable from `FETCH_HEAD` and not reachable from `foo`. If it's larger than 0, it means in the remote branch there are one or more commits you have not merged to the local `foo` yet. It's completely different from "if local commits have not been pushed".

Comment: Does this assume that the remote upstream for `foo` is also named `foo`?

Comment: Using `git rev-list --count` is much better than what I was doing. I combined our answers.

Comment: @Schwern that's okay.

Answer (score -1):

You're looking for [`git status`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status). It will give you output like:

```sh
On branch main
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/main' by 1 commit.
(use "git push" to publish your local commits)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

And you can [`grep`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) for this with:

```sh
git status | grep -E "Your branch is ahead of '.*' by ([0-9]*) commit."
```

Comment: While that's fine for humans, the format of `git status` output not stable.